# Setting the from name with nodemailer and sestransport

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I am sending emails from NodeJS using Nodemailer and sestransport on AWS, and am wondering how I can change the 'from name'?

fFr example, for from I put

```
    const mailOptions =
    {
      from:     '<noreply@example.com>',
      to:       'someone@example.com',
      subject:  'Hi',
    }
```

When I get the email, it appears to come from 'noreply'. I would like to be able to change to name to anything, for example 'tom hanks', but still have the reply address noreply@example.com. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply specify it before the email address:

```
const mailOptions =
{
  from:     '"Tom Hanks" <noreply@example.com>',
  to:       'someone@example.com',
  subject:  'Hi',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

my bad, i just found out how. just do

```
const mailOptions =
{
  from:     'Tom Hanks <noreply@example.com>',
  to:       'someone@example.com',
  subject:  'Hi',
}
```

and then the sender name appears as Tom Hanks

Answer (score 2):

You can specify [Address object](https://nodemailer.com/message/addresses/) with `name` and `address` properties. `name` property will be friendly-name for the sender, and `address` field will be the actual sender email.

```js
const mailOptions = {
  from: { name: 'Naruto Uzumaki', address: 'noreply@example.com' },
  to: 'someone@example.com',
  subject: 'Hi',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard code your name you can use template string

```
const mailOptions = 
{
  from:   `${myNameVariable} <noreplay@example.com>`,
  to:      mySenderVariable,
  subject: mySubjectVariable
}
```